# Angular unit test with fakeAsync and tick not waiting for code to execute with Observable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In my Angular application, I am trying to write a unit test case in which I have mocked the rest service response as Observable. So, I have used fakeAsync & tick in my test case. But still it is failing.

**service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class RestServices{

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}

    public post(body: any): void{
        // have variables initializations

        this._http
            .post(url, body, { observe: "response" })
            .subscribe(
                response => this._onSuccess(response),
                error => this._onFailure(error);
            );
    } 

    private _onSuccess(response: any){
        if(response.status == 200){
            // extract data from response
        }
    }

    private _onFailure(error: any){
        // code for failure
    }
}
```

**service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, tick } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { of } from "rxjs/internal/observable/of";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable";


describe("Rest", () => {
    let _service: RestServices;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const httpSpyObject = jasmine.createSpyObj("HttpClient", {
            get: of(),
            post: of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: "Text"})),
            put: of(),
        });
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                RestServices,
                { provide: HttpClient, useValue: httpSpyObject }
            ],
        });
        _service = TestBed.inject(RestServices);
    });

    it("should create", () => {
        expect(_service).toBeTruthy();
    });

   
    it("should call Success method on success response", fakeAsync(() => {
        const completeSpy = spyOn<any>(_service, "_onSuccess");
        const errorSpy = spyOn<any>(_service, "_onFailure");
        const subscrieSpy = spyOn(Observable.prototype, "subscribe");

        const body = { name: "abc" };

        _service.post(body);
        
        tick(1000);

        // Passing the below test case.
        expect(subscrieSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

        // not passing below test case
        expect(completeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
});
```

Now, How can I pass the second test case to check that **_onSuccess()** has been called from subscribe ?

Comment: I would use the `HttpClientTestingModule` for testing a service that only does http calls: https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/testing/services/http/using-httptestingmodule.

Comment: Yes. But in the doc. when any calls made it is getting subscribed in that test case only. In my case, the component method (post) doesn't return anything. That already has subscribed the data. So, @AliF50 now how can I check that success method called or not?

Comment: You can flush a response for the API call and see the `completeSpy` was called. `onComplete` is private so it will be difficult to spy on it.

Comment: @AliF50 I checked with flush it is not working and just for the testing I also changed method from private to public and still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `HttpClientTesingModule`, it will make testing much easier.

```
describe('Rest', () => {
  let service: RestService;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
       providers: [RestService],
    });
    service = Testbed.inject(RestService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    // ensure all http calls are dealt with (none in queue)
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('creates', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call success method on success response', () => {
    const successSpy = spyOn(service, 'onSuccess');
    // 2nd argument is the body
    service.post('urlGoesHere', {});

    const request = httpTestingController.expectOne('urlGoesHere');
    expect(request.request.method).toBe('Post');
    
    // send this for the response
    req.flush({});
    expect(successSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
 
});
```

Check out the above, hopefully it should get you started.

A question I have for you, is the post method takes a body but it doesn't take a URL? I think it should take a url as well.

Edit:

You may have to add `.and.callThrough()` to call the actual implementation of what you're spying on.

Like so:

```
const subscrieSpy = spyOn(Observable.prototype, "subscribe").and.callThrough();
```

Edit2:

```
let responseBody: any;
// at the beginning
// assign responseBody to response when onSuccess is called
spyOn(service, 'onSuccess').and.callFake(response => responseBody = response);
// after req.flush({});
expect(responseBody).toEqual(...);
```

Comment: Thanks @AliF50, I have specified url in environment file. So, from RestService class, I am directly accessing the environment.

Comment: Your solution is very good. And I have found the problem in my code. `const subscrieSpy = spyOn(Observable.prototype, "subscribe");` Here while spying I have to add callThrough. `const subscrieSpy = spyOn(Observable.prototype, "subscribe").and.callThrough();`. Can you please add this to your answer. So, I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: I have done the edit, thanks.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I also expect for request body? @AliF50

Comment: Do you see how `expect(request.request.method)`? Try `expect(request.request.body)`.

Comment: It is having so many parameters like normalizationNames, updates, encoder, .... So, now how should I compare my request body object with that? @AliF50

Comment: I think you can `expect(request.request.body).toEqual(body)` where body is your expected object. Use `toEqual` to assert objects and `toBe` for the rest because `toEqual` does shallow comparison (checks the contents of the array or object are the same and not the location in memory).

Comment: Yes my bad it worked. One last help I need to compare the response body. And there is no property given for that to directly compare. How can I do that? @AliF50

Comment: Isn't `expect(request.request.body).toEqual(expectedBody)` comparing the request body?

Comment: Yes it is for Request Body. Then, I asked for **response body** comparison. @AliF50

Comment: Oops sorry about that. For you it's tough to do because you subscribe in the service. Check out my edit 2 for some inspiration/ideas using `callFake`.

Comment: Thank you. @AliF50